# elastic search multiple word search not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make search query on a field which is continuous type. I have synonyms configured too. I am not getting any result for the search query.

content of synonyms.txt

```
iit, indian institute of technology
iitg, indian institute of technology guwahati
```

---

Created index institutes:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/institutes/'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/institutes/' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "suggest_synonyms": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": ["lowercase","my_synonyms"]
          }
        },
        "filter" : {
          "my_synonyms" : {
              "type" : "synonym",
              "synonyms_path" : "synonyms.txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "institute" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string","index": "not_analyzed" },
        "name_suggest" : {
          "type" :            "completion",
          "index_analyzer" :  "suggest_synonyms",
          "search_analyzer" : "suggest_synonyms",
          "preserve_position_increments": false,
          "preserve_separators": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

---

Made entries :

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/institutes/institute/3?refresh=true' -d '
{
  "name" :         "iitg",
  "name_suggest" : "iitg"
}'

curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/institutes/institute/2?refresh=true' -d '
{
  "name" :         "indian institute of technology guwahati",
  "name_suggest" : "indian institute of technology guwahati"
}'

curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/institutes/institute/1?refresh=true' -d '
{
  "name" :         "indian institute of technology",
  "name_suggest" : "indian institute of technology"
}'
```

---

Queries which are not working:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/institutes/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "name_suggest" : ["iit"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/institutes/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name_suggest": "iitg"
        }
    }
}'


curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/institutes/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name_suggest": "indian institute of technology"
        }
    }
}'
```

I am making queries on name_suggest. in my production database i dont have a column name_suggest this is something i am testing and trying things out with.

All three queries from above did not return any result. Please tell what i am doing wrong here.

UPDATE: added output of _analyze

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/institutes/_analyze?analyzer=suggest_synonyms&pretty=1' -d'
indian institute of technology guwahati
'

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "iit-g",
    "start_offset" : 1,
    "end_offset" : 40,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "iitg",
    "start_offset" : 1,
    "end_offset" : 40,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "indian",
    "start_offset" : 1,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "institute",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "of",
    "start_offset" : 18,
    "end_offset" : 20,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "technology",
    "start_offset" : 21,
    "end_offset" : 31,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "guwahati",
    "start_offset" : 32,
    "end_offset" : 40,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 5
  } ]
}
```

Thanks for not down-voting the question in advance.